# Android Studio change color in styles.xml expands my custom dialog

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` with my custom `dialog` theme that currently looks like this

[image]

This is my `styles.xml`

```
   <style name="myCustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name ="android:textColor">@color/PaleBlack</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/PaleBlack</item>
</style>
```

I also have this line in my `activity` to make the `dialog` bigger

```
 getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

However, when I try to change the `background` in my `dialog` by adding this line

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/PaleGrey</item>
```

my `activity` expands to take up the whole screen and looks like this

[image]

I want it to look like the first picture but just with a more white `background`

And also, can I remove the **black bar** at the top?

Comment: for blackbar above lolipop. add colorPrimaryDark in style.xml

Comment: @Divyesh To which attribute?

Answer (score 0):

- to change the color of your "black bar" just define `colorPrimaryDark` in your colors.xml file.
  After that, create a custom AppTheme like that in the styles.xml:

  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>`

and in the manifest.xml add the theme to your application:

`<application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

- for changing the background use the `android:background` or set the backgroundcolor programmatically with 
  `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.background_dark);`
   after you call `dialog.show;`

Comment: when i used android:background in the styles, it worked better but it changed my tab bar to white as well

when i used dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.background_dark); i got the same result as in the second picture

However, i solved it by changing the background in the activity's xml instead of the styles.xml

i have already changed colorPrimaryDark but to a blue color, but i still get that black bar

Comment: I want the theme there in my application just not in my dialog, I tried setting the colorPrimaryDark to transparent in my customDialog theme, but it just turned out grey instead..

Comment: if you follow my instructions you will apply the theme to the whole application instead to the dialog only

Comment: Yeah, and I want the action bar in the application but not in the dialog :) I tried using "getActionBar.hide();" but it gave me a null pointer exception